# Can a DLL Interface Implementation Use An Allocating Constructor?

Tags: c++, memory-management, dll, com

**I am implementing a DLL with a COM like interface and I'm using the guide set forth by:**

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL?msg=5315303#xx5315303xx

&&

http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/16/exporting-c-classes-from-a-dll

**By exporting a factory function GetXyz which returns a reference to an abstract
interface struct something like this:**

```
struct IXYZ
{
   virtual void foo(void) = 0;
   virtual void destroy()=0;
}
```

**Which is implemented by a full class XyzImple,**

```
#define XYZAPI __declspec(dllexport)

XYZAPI IXYZ* GetXyz()
{
    return new XyzImple(1,2,3);
}
//
// implementation of foo, jkl, zyx etc... 
//
//Constructor
XyzImple::XyzImple(int a, int b, int c)
{
  m_Zyx = new Zyx(a); // some ultra simple classes..
  m_Jkl = new Jkl(b); 
  m_Inty = c;
}

// 'Destroyer'
XyzImple::destroy() // Called by client side code.
{
    delete m_Zyx;
    delete m_Jkl;
    delete this; // I have seen this in tutorials..
}
```

**Is there any problems with the DLL factory function calling a constructor which also allocates dynamically, full disclosure this is my first DLL, I want to be very careful about memory leak etc.
Please refer to 'best practices' to answer this question! 
Thanks so much!**

Comment: As far as "best practice" goes, perhaps you'd want to stay away from manual memory management. That is, manual `new` and `delete` calls - in modern C++ you don't need (want) them. This looks like (bad) C++98 to me.

Comment: Factory functions should generally return `std::unique_ptr`'s.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Please correct me if I'm wrong but wouldn't that be on the client side that they would use the smart pointer to control the returned pointer from GetXyz() ? something like std::unique_ptr<IXyz> ptr(GetXyz())

Comment: @JesperJuhl @TocsBailey DLL Best Practices tend to discourage the use of STL types in a DLL's interface: There's no guarantee that `std::unique_ptr` will have the same layout across DLL boundaries. However, your implementation should definitely use `unique_ptr` for its member variables.

Comment: @JesperJuhl You wouldn't want `std::unique_ptr` on the client side either, at least not one with a default deleter. The client and the DLL may use different memory managers; the client won't necessarily be able to deallocate the memory that the DLL allocated. I assume this is the reason `IXYZ` exposes `destroy()` method (the implementation of which would do `delete this;` or similar).